# how to fix dimensions in input shape to match Conv2D() matrices using Python, OpenCV, Keras

Tags: python, opencv, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

Currently Im am learning computer vision and am practicing by making a denoise and sharpen program for blurry, noisy and out of focus images. I am using Keras for training my model, openCV, and python on a Macbook.

I am having an issue with creating the input shape to be used for my model in model.fit(), the layers of my network are using Conv2D(). The output of my terminal when trying to run my program is stating that the dimensions do not match. I am new to DL and computer vision, but I have a background in applied math so I know my matrices are not matching in their dimensions.

Any help or advice on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Terminal Output Error Followed by Code:

```
$ python sharpen_denoise.py
2023-09-12 18:25:03.054961: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
Epoch 1/5
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 699ms/step - loss: 0.0543
Epoch 2/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 58ms/step - loss: 0.0532
Epoch 3/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 50ms/step - loss: 0.0524
Epoch 4/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0516
Epoch 5/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 60ms/step - loss: 0.0504
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sharpen_denoise.py", line 59, in <module>
    output_image = denoise_and_sharpen_image(model, noisy_image)
  File "sharpen_denoise.py", line 52, in denoise_and_sharpen_image
    denoised_image = model.predict(noisy_image)
  File "/Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1751, in predict
    tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
  File "/Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 885, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 760, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3066, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3463, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3308, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1007, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 668, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 994, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    /Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:1586 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:1576 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:1569 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    /Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:1537 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    /Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1020 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /Users/infinite/opt/anaconda3/envs/opencv-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py:234 assert_input_compatibility
        str(tuple(shape)))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 64, 64)
```

CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


# Create and Compile Deep Learning Model

def create_model(input_shape):
    model = keras.Sequential()

    # Encoder
    model.add(layers.Input(shape=input_shape))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))

    # decoder
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))

    return model


input_shape = (256, 256, 1)  # Adjust input_shape to size of image
model = create_model(input_shape)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')


# Load and Preprocess Noisy Image
def load_and_preprocess_image(image_path):
    image = cv.imread(image_path, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = cv.resize(image, input_shape[:2])
    image = image / 255.0  # Normalize Pixel Values to [0,1]
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)  # Add Batch Dimension
    return image


noisy_image = load_and_preprocess_image(
    '/Users/infinite/Desktop/PythonPractice/openCV/photos/Noisy_Image.jpg')  # Load Image Path

# Train the Model
model.fit(tf.expand_dims(noisy_image, axis=-1), noisy_image, epochs=5)
#model.fit(noisy_image, noisy_image, epochs=100, batch_size=1)


# Use Trained Model To Sharpen and DeBlur
def denoise_and_sharpen_image(model, noisy_image):
    denoised_image = model.predict(noisy_image)
    denoised_image = denoised_image.squeeze()  # Remove the Batch Dimension
    denoised_image = cv.normalize(denoised_image, None, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
    denoised_image = denoised_image.astype(np.uint8)
    return denoised_image


output_image = denoise_and_sharpen_image(model, noisy_image)

# Display The Noisy and Denoised Images
cv.imshow('Noisy Image', noisy_image.squeeze())
cv.imshow('Denoised_Image', output_image)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error backtrace shows that the error occurs in the `denoise_and_sharpen_image` function, so the training part works.

However, note the difference between how you train your network and how you use it for inference:

```
model.fit(tf.expand_dims(noisy_image, axis=-1), noisy_image, epochs=5)
```

versus

```
denoised_image = model.predict(noisy_image)
```

The input dimensions are different.
If, instead you call `predict` like this:

```
denoised_image = model.predict(tf.expand_dims(noisy_image, axis=-1))
```

It will work, because this way you'll have the same number of dimensions